# ejemplo pausar delay no me funciona

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema, el caso es que estoy haciendo un control de delay que conrole las acciones en un proceso al presionar pause o resumir.

mi intencion es pausar controlar el redireccionamiento de los click usando ese menu pero no me funciona

luego de subir un archivo que muestre el delay- que pause y continue segun se presione el boton . y que continue al otro , ejm. btn1->btn2->btn3-> asi todo el rato

```js
  var pause, resumir,tiemporestante , boton1 , boton2;
  
var c = 5;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = "redireccionando en "+c+"...";
  c = c - 1;
  t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
  //Si se cumple el tiempo lo redireccionamos.
  if(c==0){
     stopCount();
     //redireccionar...
     console.log("redireccionado");
  }
}

function startCount() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = 1;
    timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on = 0;
}

boton1 = document.createElement("input");
    boton1.id="boton1";
    boton1.textContent = "boton1";
    
    boton1.type = "file";
    boton1.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado, false);
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
boton1.addEventListener('change',function (){
alert("archivo subido");
/* me muestra el alert pero no controla el evento de darle al click al boton si se pulsa pause o resumir*/
timedCount()
 $( "#boton2" ).click();
});


body.appendChild(boton1);

boton2 = document.createElement("button");
    boton2.id="boton2";
    boton2.textContent = "boton2";
    boton2.innerHTML = "boton2";
    boton2.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado, false);
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(boton2);



  pause = document.createElement("button");
    pause.id="pause";
    pause.textContent = "pause";
    pause.innerHTML = "pause";
    pause.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado, false);
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(pause);

    resumir = document.createElement("button");
    resumir.id="resumir";
    resumir.textContent = "resumir";
    resumir.innerHTML = "resumir";
    resumir.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado, false);
var body2 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(resumir);


    tiemporestante = document.createElement("input");
    tiemporestante.id="txt";
    tiemporestante.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado, false);
var body3 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(tiemporestante);


function botonpresionado() {
  console.log("Se presionó: " + this.id);
  
  
 
  
  
  
  if(this.id =="resumir"){
timedCount()
}
if(this.id =="pause"){
stopCount()
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://tus.io/demo.html

Comment: esta bonito, ya lo implementare